# How can we call oneDrive data into SPFx webpart, which is hosted in SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp, react

We need to get the information of all the OneDrive folders and its files in SPFx webpart and this webpart is hosted in another SharePoint site. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the data from onedrive into SPFx, you can try graph API
Below link will help you getting started.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online.

If you want to explore what all can be achieved with Graph API below link will list APIs
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem?view=odsp-graph-online#methods

ex. To get All items you have "/drive/items/{item-id}"

You will need to have proper premissions for your code to access graph API in SPFx.

Answer (score 0):

As Akshay said,you could use graph api to get files in one drive.

Demo on spfx Use the MSGraphClient to connect to Microsoft Graph.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHzbh5JoC-A